# How to have a Visualforce page with a dynamic criteria in a Report Chart

Tags: visualforce, custom-reports

I would like to have a Visualforce page in a record which displays a report. I want the report to have run a query in the report based on the value of a field in the record in which it is being run.

In other word, if the Color__c field value for the record is "Red" I would like for that to be put into the criteria of the report. (ie Color__c = "Red").

Is this possible ? As it is now, I am displaying the report just by doing this :

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" >
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005fPDb" >
  </analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

...but I would like the field value put into the criteria dynamically.

I'm guessing this is not possible....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter attribute to add additional filters. A minimal change looks like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" >
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005fPDb" filter="[{ column:'Color__c',operator:'equals',value:'{!Custom_Object__c.Color__c}'}]">
  </analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it also possible to show the body of the report with a filter ? All I am able to find are methods of iframe such as this : 

<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" >
  <apex:iframe src="/00O900000020jcA"/>  <!—Report id -->
</apex:page>


But I don't think I can apply a filter to that, can I ?

Comment: @Zoom_v No, that wouldn't work, but you could use the [ReportManager](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm) class to run a report with additional filters and render your own data table.